# Solution of Inexact differential equation $x\sin(y)\,dy+(x^3-2(x^2)\cos(y)+\cos(y))\,dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

$$x\sin(y)\,dy+(x^3-2x^2\cos(y)+\cos(y))\,dx$$
i tried solving the above d.e. the integrating factor comes out to be $e^{\int p\, dx}$
where $p$ was found out to be $x^2e^{-x^2}$.

But the resulting d.e after multiplying the integration factor turn out to be inexact.
I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\sin(y)dy+(x^3-2(x^2)\cos(y)+\cos(y))dx=0$$
$$-xd\cos(y)+x^3dx+(-2x^2+1)\cos(y)dx=0$$
$$d\cos(y)-x^2dx+(2x-\dfrac 1 x)\cos(y)dx=0$$
The integrating factor should be :
$$\mu(x)=e^{x^2-\ln x}=\dfrac {e^{x^2}}{x}$$
Then the DE becomes exact.
$$d  \left (\cos(y)\dfrac {e^{x^2}}{x} \right)-xe^{x^2}dx=0$$
$$d  \left (\cos(y)\dfrac {e^{x^2}}{x} \right)-\dfrac 12d (e^{x^2})=0$$
Integrate.

---

It seems to me that your integrating factor should be:
$$\mu(x)=-\dfrac {e^{x^2}}{x^2}$$
And not $x^2e^{-x^2}$